# 'GROUPING SETS ( ) ' function groups the fields in the reverse order in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
select continent , country , city , sum(units_sold)
from Sales
group by GROUPING SETS (continent,country,city)
```

While executing the above query, the result set is first grouped by city, country and then continent.

I expected the result set to be grouped by continent first, country second and city third , as I have specified in the grouping sets. But the query returns the resultset in reversed order.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzeqV.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Demonstrate what your expected results are, the *image* (which again, is not helpful), is correct for what you asked; you asked to group your data in 3 different sets: one set `continent`, another set on  `country` and the last set on `city`.

Answer (score 3):

Order in SQL is never guaranteed, the server is always free to order it as it sees fit, unless you specify `ORDER BY`.

You can use the `GROUPING` function to determine which columns are grouped. It will return `1` if the column has been rolled up.

```sql
SELECT
  continent,
  country,
  city,
  SUM(units_sold)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (continent),
  (country),
  (city)
)
ORDER BY
  GROUPING(continent),
  continent,
  GROUPING(country),
  country,
  GROUPING(city),
  city;
```